# Working with a local project (localhost:8080), how can I send emails?

Tags: jsp, email, netbeans, localhost

I'm trying to send e-mails out from a JSP project I'm working on locally in NetBeans 7.4.

I have a standard script for sending an email but I'm getting the following error:

"Couldn't connect to host, port: localhost, 25; timeout -1"

Obviously there's another step, something I have to install on my Mac or something so I can send mail using the built in methods for sending emails in JSP, something that comes already installed when you purchase a JSP-ready web host.

Anyhow, anyone can tell me?

Thanks,
TF

Answer (score 1):

You need an SMTP server to use localhost has your [MTA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mail_transfer_agent). You could mock a SMTP server using

- [Mock SMTP Server](http://mocksmtpserver.codeplex.com/)
- [Dumbster](http://quintanasoft.com/dumbster/)

or you could use a real MTA such as -

[Exchange](http://www.office.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/) (Commercial from MS)

[QMail](http://qmail.org/) (Opensource)

[Sendmail](http://www.sendmail.com/sm/open_source/) (Opensource)

or you could use a different host (running one of the above) instead of localhost.